# Could not load file or assembly 'Moq,4.2.1502.911, or one of its dependencies

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, moq, nuget-package

I have Moq nuget package installed from Manage Nuget Packages for my project. Project builds successfully but when i run the test case, it throws following error

```
System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Moq, Version=4.2.1502.911, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=69f491c39445e920' or one of its dependencies
```

I checked project references and Moq.dll is there.

Also i noticed this on output window for test run

```
------ Discover test started ------
Unable to load the test container 'C:\dev\tfs\Main\GUI\Gui.Client\Bin\Debug\Gui.Client.dll' or one of its dependencies. Error details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows, Version=5.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.Prism, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Windows, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

========== Discover test finished: 20 found (0:00:03.4941998) ==========
------ Run test started ------
Warning: conflict during test run deployment: deployment item 'c:\dev\tfs\main\gui\test\gui.client.state.tests\bin\debug\Moq.dll' directly or indirectly referenced by the test container 'c:\dev\tfs\main\gui\test\gui.client.state.tests\bin\debug\gui.client.state.tests.dll' cannot be deployed to 'Moq.dll' because otherwise the file 'c:\dev\tfs\main\gui\test\gui.client.state.tests\bin\debug\Moq.dll' would overwrite deployment item '..\ThirdPartyLibraries\NuGetPackages\Moq.4.2.1402.2112\lib\net40\Moq.dll' specified by the test settings.
Warning: Test Run deployment issue: The assembly or module 'NMath' directly or indirectly referenced by the test container 'c:\dev\tfs\main\gui\test\gui.client.state.tests\bin\debug\gui.client.state.tests.dll' was not found.
========== Run test finished: 1 run (0:00:23.2373118) ==========
```

Comment: Have you found a solution to this issue? I run into similar problem with the same error. I have some nuget packages for testing (and I susupect that Ninject.MockingKernel is the trigger of this behaviour) and they work just fine in VS test runer nunit plugin (tests executed and work just fine), but in nunit gui I get this error and spending some time could not localise this issue.

Comment: Make sure the user running VS got read access to dll folder. You can also try re-install Nuget packages.

Answer (score 11):

Had the same problem.
Updated the Moq nugets for all projects to they all use the same Moq library and it worked fine for me.

right click on your Moq reference and make sure that you are using the same version everywhere. if not update the using nuget package manager

Comment: This did not work for me - using TFS 15 as a build server.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was that I had "Enable Native Code Debugging" selected as well as "Suppress Jit Compilation". Deselected these, clean and build, and the problem was no longer there.